# Does the filename store in ~/.vim/view have particular meaning?

Tags: terminal

I noticed that in my ~/.vim/view folder all the file have the following format:

```
'~=+Documents=+temp=+IADS_cwk2=+iads_cw2.tex='  '~=+tempdir=+temp=+web=+blog1.html='                    '~=+t.tex='
'=+etc=+X11=+xorg.conf='                        '~=+tempdir=+temp=+web=+index.html='                    '~=+t.txt='
'~=+notes.txt='                                 '~=+tempdir=+test=+aa.txt='                             '=+usr=+share=+vim=+vim82=+doc=+help.txt='
'~=+tempdir=+CV=+CV.tex='                       '~=+tempdir=+test=+t2.tex='                             '=+usr=+share=+vim=+vim82=+doc=+options.txt='
'~=+tempdir=+CV=+.gitignore='                   '~=+tempdir=+test=+t3.tex='                             '=+usr=+share=+vim=+vim82=+doc=+starting.txt='
'~=+tempdir=+notes=+.gitignore='                '~=+tempdir=+test=+~==+tempdir==+test==+test.txt==='    '=+usr=+share=+vim=+vim82=+doc=+syntax.txt='
'~=+tempdir=+notes=+rl_qf_report.tex='          '~=+tempdir=+test=+==+t.tex='                           '~=+.vim=+mySnips=+tex.snippets='
'~=+tempdir=+notes=+rl.tex='                    '~=+tempdir=+test=+t.tex='                              '~=+.vim=+plugged=+vimtex=+doc=+vimtex.txt='
'~=+tempdir=+notes=+stat.t='                    '~=+tempdir=+test=+tt=+tt.txt='                         '~=+.vimrc='
'~=+tempdir=+notes=+stat.tex='                  '~=+tempdir=+Yuanhao-JIANG.github.io=+css=+style.css='  '~=+.vim=+view=+~==+tempdir==+test==+t2.tex==='
'~=+tempdir=+rmed.txt='                         '~=+tempdir=+Yuanhao-JIANG.github.io=+index.html='
```

does this format, replacing the `/` in the file path to `=+`, have specific meaning? Is it just for vim to look for the file or is it also use in elsewhere like in bash script as another way to find a file?

Comment: According to `:help :mkview`, they are generated names. I'm sure it helps `:loadview` function correctly